# C++ FastCGI parsing POST requests in to various form fields

Tags: c++, field, fastcgi

I am writing a C++ app on FastCGI using libfcgi++. When I do a POST or GET request, is there a library out there that would parse the different fields?

For example for a GET /fastcgi.fcgi?var1=data1&var2=data2 would return something that's easier to access var1 and var2?

Same for a multipart POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [fastcgi++](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/) might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

FastCGI works with CGICC library. CGICC is excellent for your needs.